# Call void function inside of controller

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have following controller:

```
public ActionResult delete(int id)
    {
        //call function
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

here I want to call following function from my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace project1.Models.Admin
{
public class delete
{
    public void delete(int id)
        {
        //xxx
        const string ConnStr = "...";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
        connection.Open(); 
        MySqlCommand sqlcmd2;
        sqlcmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
        sqlcmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE `user` SET Aktive = 0 WHERE Nr = @id;";

        sqlcmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = id;

        sqlcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
        //xxx
    }

}
}
```

I get the error that "void" isn't allowed in this context. Is there any other way to call my function here or should I put the whole connection (inside "xxx") into my controller?

Comment: You cannot use `delete` within a class with that name. Having said this `delete` is a really bad name for a class. Aprt from this you should follow naming-conventions, e.g. use PascaleCase-names for both methods and classes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere my first language isnt english so i changed the names in english for better understanding. but still thanks good thing to know.

Comment: Mine neither and I guess only a few persons here nativly speak english. Anyway the conventions exist for good reason.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i meant my names for classes,functions,... arent in english. i only changed it in my question so you guys maybe understand it better. but still thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change method name;

```
public void deleteFunc(int id)
```

**EDIT**

Firstly, you should be careful about naming convention. I change your class name like `DeleteAction` and method name `DeleteRecord`

```
public class DeleteAction
{
    public void DeleteRecord(int id)
    {
        //xxx
        const string ConnStr = "...";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand sqlcmd2;
        sqlcmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
        sqlcmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE `user` SET Aktive = 0 WHERE Nr = @id;";

        sqlcmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = id;

        sqlcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
        //xxx
    }

}
```

Then, you can call desired function by creating an instance from class;

```
public ActionResult delete(int id)
{
    var deleteActionObject = new DeleteAction();
    deleteActionObject.DeleteRecord(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: what is the right way to call the function in the controller?

Comment: That answer only handles the obvious (syntactic) problems, not the *actual* problem, that OP doesn´t know how to call the method.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems in your code.

First you cannot use `delete` as both a class- and a member-name. Having said this `delete` is a really bad name for a class.

Second you should follow naming-conventions, e.g. use PascalCase-names for both methods and classes.

And last and most important, you need an instance of your class of which you want to call the method:

```
public ActionResult delete(int id)
{
    myInstanceOfDeleteClass.delete(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If you don´t have an instance of that class, you may also make `delete` a `static` one. Then you could directly call the method within your controller:

```
public ActionResult delete(int id)
{
    DeleteClass.Delete(id);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public class DeleteClass
{
    public static void Delete(int id)
    {
        //xxx
        const string ConnStr = "...";

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
        connection.Open(); 
        MySqlCommand sqlcmd2;
        sqlcmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();
        sqlcmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE `user` SET Aktive = 0 WHERE Nr = @id;";

        sqlcmd2.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = id;

        sqlcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connection.Close();
        //xxx
    }

}
```